# Order of items in a checklist vs the order those items are checked off

Tags: checkboxes, ordering, sidebar, options

I have a modal with a sidebar of checkboxes that, when checked, append options to a panel on the right for the user to customize.

Example:

> [image: selecting Relationship option inserts relationship section at top of adjacent form]

My question: I currently have the items being appended to the top of previously added items in the order that they are checked off. I do this because I think the user should see what is being added as they check the boxes, as opposed to the item appending to the bottom of the scrollable area. Are there any use cases that would suggest the order of the criteria in the right panel should always match the order of their respective checkboxes in the left panel?

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be filling the form below the scroll fold and add a top section you'll not only have the same problem of not seeing the section appear right in front of you but also experience your current view being pushed down by the new content which very is annoying.

I'd suggest going with an accordion of collapsible sections like below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNv5An.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>